# GUITexture component's border settings only stretching left?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am having trouble using the GUITexture component's border settings, in the inspector I have set leftBorder, rightBorder, topBorder, and bottomBorder, to specify how many pixels on each edge will be unstretched.

However this is the result, as you can see my image only correctly stretches to the left.

[image: The result of my slicing only strecthing to the left]

And this is even though I have correctly (I think?) sliced the sprite as following.

[image: The way the slicing was setup]

Incase it helps here are the settings on the rect transform that I use to hold the image.

[image: Extra settings for better information]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question, turns out when importing my spritesheet I had to turn off "Generate Mip Maps"

[image]